# Visual Studio dynamic allocation of a multidimensional array

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, dynamic-memory-allocation

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

int main(void){
int n, i, j;

printf("Enter the number of rows and columns: ");
scanf("%d", &n);

int **matrix = malloc(n * sizeof(int *));

for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    matrix[i] = malloc(n * sizeof(int *));

// Read the matrix
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
   for(j=0; j<n; j++){
            printf("matrix[%d][%d]= ",i+1,j+1);
            scanf("%d",&matrix[i][j]);
            }

// Print the matrix
for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
    printf("%\n");
    for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
        printf("%d", matrix[i][j]);
}


// Free the allocated memory
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
  for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
     free((void *)matrix[i]);

free(matrix);

// Just checking if the memory has been freed
for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
  printf("%\n");
     for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
        printf("%d ", matrix[i][j]);
}

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

I was just trying to dynamically allocate a matrix. Even though in CodeBlocks everything works fine, since we work with Visual Studio at the University, I decided to test the code in VS 2010. I was surprised that I have so many errors and that the code wont compile.
I would like to know how could I fix the problem so VS would compile the code just fine.

Here are the errorrs:

```
(10): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
(13): error C2065: 'matrix' : undeclared identifier
(13): error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type
(19): error C2065: 'matrix' : undeclared identifier
(19): error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type
(26): error C2065: 'matrix' : undeclared identifier
(26): error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type
(33): error C2065: 'matrix' : undeclared identifier
(33): error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type
(33): error C2198: 'free' : too few arguments for call
(35): error C2065: 'matrix' : undeclared identifier
(35): warning C4022: 'free' : pointer mismatch for actual parameter 1
(41): error C2065: 'matrix' : undeclared identifier
(41): error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type
```

Comment: The errors should give you a hint of how to correct the code.

Comment: variable declaration placed at the beginning of the block.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    matrix[i] = malloc(n * sizeof(int *));
```

change above to

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    matrix[i] = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
```

--

```
// Read the matrix
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
   for(j=0; j<n; j++){
            printf("matrix[%d][%d]= ",i+1,j+1);
            scanf("%d",&matrix[i][j]);
            }
```

also change above to

```
// Read the matrix
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
   for(j=0; j<n; j++){
            printf("matrix[%d][%d]= ",i+1,j+1);
            scanf("%d",&matrix[i][j]);
            }
```

--

```
// Free the allocated memory
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
  for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
     free((void *)matrix[i]);

free(matrix);
```

also change above to

```
// Free the allocated memory

for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
     free((void *)matrix[i]);
     matrix[i] = NULL;
}

free(matrix);
```

--

```
// Just checking if the memory has been freed
for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
  printf("%\n");
     for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
        printf("%d ", matrix[i][j]);
}
```

the above was totally wrong

Comment: I was just curious what it would display after using the free function. Anyway in CodeBlocks worked just fine giving me useless amount of numbers, so I found what I needed to know. In VS crashed! So it's enough to free one array and the other one will automatically free itself like you did in the code above?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that Visual Studio's C compiler only supports the 1989 standard not the later 1999 & 2011 standards.

A key difference between C89 and the later versions is that C89 only allows variable declarations at the top of a block before any other code.

What this means is that you have to declare matrix before you call printf or scanf, like so:

```
int main(void){
   int n, i, j;
   int **matrix;

   printf("Enter the number of rows and columns: ");
   scanf("%d", &n);

   matrix = malloc(n * sizeof(int *));
```

That should cure the compilation errors you're seeing. Check V_Maenolis' answer for some other problems with your code.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that Visual Studio uses C89.